# Android Google Maps API, naming Markers?

Tags: android, google-maps

how can the user input text when creating a Marker so the Marker gets the name the user inputs? Like an AlertDialog? 
Here's the marker-creation code:

```
googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(point)
                    .title("Hello world"));


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code snippet

```
  googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {

               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
               builder.setTitle("Title");

              // Set up the input
              final EditText input = new EditText(this);
              builder.setView(input);

              // Set up the buttons
              builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             String text = input.getText().toString();
                             googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                             .position(point)
                             .title(text));
              }
              });
           builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
           }); 
           builder.show();      
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but it says "Builder/TextEdit cannot be applied to anonymous com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener" and that "point" needs to be declared "final"

Comment: Solved the first bit but still says that "point" need to be final

Comment: i did not compile code. of course it must be declared **final** . Just add final modifier infront of the point.